# I want to test the Animator component of a gameobject using nunit, but I am having issues

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, test-driven-development

I made a Blender 3D model with animations. Then I used the Animator Controller, and attached it to the model. The Animator Controller has a few Boolean parameter variables like `isWaving`, `isDoing`, and `isIdle` and more variables like that. If, say, a non-idle action is true, then the animation of my model transitions to the next one. I am into test-driven development, but I have never done it with Unity.

---

I tried writing the following code to test my project:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    Crystal = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CrystalModel");
    CrystalScript = Crystal.GetComponent<CrystalChanPlayer>();
    CrystalAnimator = Crystal.GetComponent<Animator>(); // unity game animator
}

[Test]
public void ifSetAnimationIstodoThenToDoAnimationIsPlayed()
{
    CrystalScript.setAnimationStrategy("todo"); // set strategy
    CrystalScript.playAnimation(); // sets todo boolean to true and idle to false

    // first debug output
    Debug.LogError("todo is " + CrystalAnimator.GetBool("isDoing") + 
        " idle is " + CrystalAnimator.GetBool("isIdle"));

    //second output
    Debug.LogError("current state is " + 
        CrystalAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("idle"));

    Assert.True(CrystalAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("todoAnimation"));
}
```

I received the following output:

> "todo is true and idle is false"
>   "true"

---

I think this is because Unity isn't really running, and my Animator doesn't get to update based on the variable changes. The first output assures me that `todo` is set to `true` and `idle` is `false`, hence the Animator should transition that animation to the `todoAnimation`. Yet, I can't seem to show that, in my tests.

Is there any way to test the Animator class? Are there any design patterns I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing my animators by always using `animator.Update(0.1f)` to make them pass from states to states.

You should try this after your following triggers.

```
CrystalScript.setAnimationStrategy("todo"); // set strategy
CrystalScript.playAnimation(); // sets todo boolean to true and idle to false
CrystalScript.Update(0.1f);
```

Some times I also manually call Awake()/Start() on my scripts, as you said, unity is not running at this time so you have to mock the sequencing manually.

Let me know it does any good.